# value gets undefined between Controllers nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I'm trying to use a var value in other file and if I define it on the begin of my code it raises the error "Cannot read property 'stats' of null" so I try to use globals but that doesn't help, always get null in my other file.

I need to get listaLive, listaRepeated and listaPasserBy values in other file where I send this data to process them and then insert in db (AgregateController).

At the time my code is:

```
 ProbingController.prototype.pollingAllDevices = function () {
    createLog('info', __dirname, __filename.slice(__dirname.length + 1, -3), null, 'probing', 'inicio');
    var numDevices = 1;
    return Database.Devices.getDevices().then(function (devices) {
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            async.each(devices, function (device, callback) {
               logger.info('WSController-Service', 'probing', 'getRadioInfo  --> ', device.id, ' :: ', numDevices++, '/', devices.length);
                //stats ubus call wsniffer stats pie chart
                //list  ubus call wsniffer list
                //listex ubus call wsniffer  listex

                    var obj = {
                        "id": uuid.v4(),
                       // "timestamp": new Date().getTime(),
                        "device_id": device.id,
                        "data":{
                            "stats":{
                            },
                            "list":{
                            }
                        }
                    };

                    var allPromises=[];                 

                    allPromises.push(Controllers.Gps.getRadioInfo('wsniffer', 'stats', {}, device));
                    allPromises.push(Controllers.Gps.getRadioInfo('wsniffer', 'list', {}, device));

                    Promise.all(allPromises).then(function(values){
                        console.log("probing values -> "+device.id+" "+ JSON.stringify(values));    
                        for(var j=0;j<values.length;j++){
                            if(values[j]!=null){
                                console.log("stats "+device.id+" --> "+ values[0]["stats"]);
                                console.log("list "+device.id+" --> "+ values[1]["list"]);
                                if(values.stats["stats"]!=undefined){
                                    obj.data.stats = values[0]["stats"];
                                }
                                if(values.stats["list"]!=undefined){
                                    obj.data.list = values[1]["list"];
                                }                               
                            }
                        }
                        var countRepetidos=0;
                        if(obj["list"]!=undefined && obj["list"].length>0){                     

                            var aux = obj["list"];
                            for(var j=1;j<aux.length;j++){
                                var tmp = aux;
                                for(var k=1;k<tmp.length;k++){
                                    if(j!=k){
                                        if(aux[j] === tmp[k]){
                                            countRepetidos++;
                                            aux.splice(k,1);
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        var dataLive = [];
                        var dataRepeated= [];
                        var dataPasserBy = [];

                        var now = Date.now();

                        var listaLive=[], listaRepeated=[], listaPasserBy=[];

                        if(obj.data.stats!=undefined){
                            dataLive = [obj.data.stats.since, obj.data.stats.live];
                            dataPasserBy = [obj.data.stats.since, obj.data.stats.passerby];
                        }

                        dataRepeated = [obj.data.stats.since, countRepetidos];


                        createLog('debug', __dirname, __filename.slice(__dirname.length + 1, -3), device.id, 'probing', 'obj', obj);

                        listaLive.push(dataLive);
                        listaRepeated.push(dataRepeated);
                        listaPasserBy.push(dataPasserBy);

                        Controllers.Agregate.agregateData("probing_live", 5 * 60, listaLive, dbHistConnectionString, device.id, device.network_id, device.organization_id, ["time","clients"]);
                        Controllers.Agregate.agregateData("probing_repeated", 5 * 60, listaRepeated, dbHistConnectionString, device.id, device.network_id, device.organization_id, ["time","clients"]);
                        Controllers.Agregate.agregateData("probing_passerBy", 5 * 60, listaPasserBy, dbHistConnectionString, device.id, device.network_id, device.organization_id, ["time","clients"]);
                        Database.Probing.addRow(obj);

                        global.listaLive = listaLive;
                        global.listaRepeated = listaRepeated
                        global.listaPasserBy = listaPasserBy


                    }).catch(function (e) { // error handling
                        console.log("probing - promiseall ",device.id,e);
                        if(values==null){
                            console.log('probing values null ---->', device.id);
                        }
                        createLog('error', __dirname, __filename.slice(__dirname.length + 1, -3), device.id, 'probing', 'no promise all',e);
                        return callback(e);
                    });


            }, function (error) {
                if (error) {
                    createLog('error', __dirname, __filename.slice(__dirname.length + 1, -3), null, 'probing', 'stops polling?!', error);
                    return reject(error);
                }
                createLog('info', __dirname, __filename.slice(__dirname.length + 1, -3), null, 'probing','All Devices Processed');
                return resolve();
            });
        }).catch(function (e) {
            console.log("probing 1--> ",e);
            createLog('error', __dirname, __filename.slice(__dirname.length + 1, -3), null, 'probing','promise',e);
        });
    }).catch(function (e) {
        console.log("probing 2--> ",e);
        createLog('error', __dirname, __filename.slice(__dirname.length + 1, -3), null, 'probing','getDevices',e);
    });

}
```

Logs:

```
 3|wscontro | probing stats  { since: 1500454284751,
3|wscontro | probing list  [ '00:05:ca:e4:85:39',
3|wscontro | probing dataStatsSince -->  1500454284751
3|wscontro | probing dataStatsLive -->  236
3|wscontro | probing dataStatsPasserBy -->  134
3|wscontro | probing listaLive -->  [ [ 1500454284751, 236 ] ]
3|wscontro | probing listaRepeated -->  [ [ 1500454284751, 0 ] ]
3|wscontro | probing listaPasserBy -->  [ [ 1500454284751, 134 ] ]



3|wscontro | [2017-07-18 15:07:42.834] - debug: /opt/wscontroller/wscontroller-service/scripts/agregate AgregateController b2aaba26-dea0-4b2e-9b6e-6fe91c566ee9 recursviva data  {"id":"c0a2941f-e617-4c14-95de-4506565b28d1","agregation_period":300,"medium":[0],"maximum":[0],"minimum":[0],"timestamp":[null,0],"sum":[null],"type":"probing_repeated","device_id":"b2aaba26-dea0-4b2e-9b6e-6fe91c566ee9","network_id":"7e709c63-45c5-4716-b596-ece3468b25f9","organization_id":"ce4b69af-bdce-4f1b-ba71-dd03544205d5","labels":["time","clients"]}
```

Where "timestamp" and "sum" are the values on the agregate inside of listaLive, listaRepeated and listaPasserBy.

```
3|wscontro | probing timestamp  [ undefined, 0 ]
3|wscontro | probing sum  undefined
```

I need this values of the list on agregator...

Comment: Where are you trying to use a variable in a different file? What line is giving you that error? If this is Node.js, don't use global variables. Use modules.

Comment: I was using the commented line //obj["data"].stats=statsData["stats"] to use the data and it raises the error given but after if filled the error doenst appear anymore understand... when is still empty raises the error ... I need this data on the AgregateController understand.. but in this file the data passed are null...

Answer (score 0):

You can share any value you want using the `exports` object.

So try to export your var variable using exports. Example:

```
**helper.js** 

const hello = 'hello world'
exports.hello = hello

**index.js**

const example = require('./helper.js').hello
console.log(example) //Will show 'hello world'
```

Comment: I understand.. if i use resolve i cant pass the value? Is not any way? :\ http://plnkr.co/edit/telrz9HAdVEwq18pJ5js?p=preview my code here

Comment: I think I misunderstood your question. If you are using promises using resolve you can pass any data you want. Once you call your promise in other file the ```then``` method will follow your variable for sure. Here you have some documentation that can help your with this https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve

Comment: I tried to do in the code resolve(listaLive) and nothing happend on the other file... how can i do?  http://plnkr.co/edit/telrz9HAdVEwq18pJ5js?p=preview my code updated